# Spring Security: How can I access SessionRegistry inside custom UserDetailsService?

Tags: spring, security, session, registry, userdetailsservice

I am getting the following error message

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry]
found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire 
candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

given the following Spring Security 4 setup:

**Spring security configuration:**

```
...
<x509 subject-principal-regex="CN=(.*?)," user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
...
<custom-filter ref="concurrencyFilter" after="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" />
<session-management>
    <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
                         error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"
                         session-registry-ref="sessionRegistry" />
</session-management>

<beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
            <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry"/>
            <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/logout" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry"
            class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
</authentication-manager>
...
```

**Custom UserDetailsService:**

```
...
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private SessionRegistryImpl sessionRegistry;
    ...
}
```

Any idea why `SessionRegistryImpl` fails to be injected into my custom `UserDetailsService`?  I tried various permutations, e.g. `session-registry-alias` instead of `session-registry-ref`, and `@Resource(name="sessionRegistry")` instead of `@Autowired`, etc. but none worked for me.  I am stuck, and any help will be greatly appreciated!